# Java method requires argument even though it is not used

Tags: java, android, methods, arguments

So, I'm messing around in Android Studio, and I have a method that looks like this:

```
public void check(View view) {
        EditText numberEditText = findViewById(R.id.number);
        int number = Integer.parseInt(numberEditText.getText().toString());
        Toast.makeText(this, getMessage(number), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

The method is called when a button is pressed, and works as expected. However, when I remove the argument from the method, leaving

```
public void check() {
        EditText numberEditText = findViewById(R.id.number);
        int number = Integer.parseInt(numberEditText.getText().toString());
        Toast.makeText(this, getMessage(number), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    },
```

the app crashes whenever the button is pressed. I find this weird, since I'm not actually using the `View` that is passed along. I assume it is some issue with the `View` being passed along and me not taking any arguments. Is there any way to get around taking the `View` in the method? I think it makes the code more difficult to read when the method takes an argument it doesn't use.

Here's the stacktrace:

```
08-08 19:37:55.120 11217-11217/com.example.corfi.numbershapes E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.corfi.numbershapes, PID: 11217
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method check(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button3'
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:424)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:381)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: can you please integrate your question adding the stacktrace of the error?

Comment: I've added it above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have implemented the click listener via the xml layout where you set the

```
android:onClick="click"
```

Now due to this, the expected click listener function is

```
public void click(View view){}
```

The android controller passed the view to this activity when the button is clicked and thus the system will come to know what was clicked.

An alternate to this is not adding the listener inside the layout and adding a listener in your code

remove the android:onClick part from the layout xml

Then in your code, find the view of the button first

```
Button yourbutton =  findViewById('R.id.yourbuttonid');
```

Now set a click listener on this

```
yourbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          //Do your thing
        }

});
```

Even here, you can see that the inner method has a View passed. This is by design

Answer (score 1):

The View will be delivered for each case of your listener, if you want to remove anonymous listeners and View parameter, you can try [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/), you can use it as below

```
@OnClick(R.id.yourButtonId)
public void onYourButtonClick(){
    //your logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference a view in param because it how android work to find the listener of view component.

If you look [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener), the standard method also put view in parameter, like this block of code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         setContentView(R.layout.content_layout_id);

         final Button button = findViewById(R.id.button_id);
         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

             // On click method has parameter View v
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 // Code here executes on main thread after user presses button
             }
         });
     }
 }
```